# Does Stack Exchange take any measures against sites violating our license?

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing, attribution, creative-commons

I updated an answer of mine with an improved solution:

- [Does PostgreSQL support "accent insensitive" collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)

I hit Google to find related answers that might be outdated now, just to find this:

https://fmdojo.wordpress.com/2014/05/14/remove-accents-in-postgresql-quitar-acentos/

And many other sites just like it.

My verbatim answer without any attribution. Besides legal and moral aspects, there is also no link to the updated solution. I am happy to share, or I wouldn't post here to begin with. But I am not happy about ... this.

Our license clearly requires attribution:

> user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) required

And Jeff is clear about attribution in the linked blog post:

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

I wonder, does Stack Exchange take any ***measures*** against known offenders? Can it even? Would it make any sense?

Comment: Most scrapers don't provide any attribution or it is incomplete. It is hardly ever correct.

Comment: Yeah, having *"Stack Exchange content is being reproduced without attribution"* under *"Contact"* is somewhat disingenuous (e.g., most users will not register it in the long canned message. And it is too late; the unnecessary  busy work is already done). It implies something that isn't.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413386/i-reported-a-copycat-site-content-farm-and-was-responded-with-this-may-help-y/413407#413407) (MSO).